# Turn off location suggestions in Calendar

Tags: calendar

On my iMac (10.13.6) and MacBook (10.15.3), whenever I add a new event to the Calendar app and attempt to enter a location, a dropdown list of suggested locations appears:

[image]

How can I turn these suggestions off?

I have tried to disable the Calendar app in System Preferences > Security > Privacy > Location Services as well as turning off "Location Based Suggestions" for System Services under the same path, as suggested [here](https://www.cultofmac.com/450375/disable-location-suggestions-macos-sierra/), but these settings had no effect.

Comment: This suggestion dropdown is rather simple-minded and annoying. I added an event to meet with one of our IT people. Location: I typed IT, and very helpfully Calendar suggested "Italy" as the first of many, completely irrelevant others. Desperately looking for a solution to get rid of this behaviour :-)